# How can I perform case-insensitive pattern search and case-preserving replacement?

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

Here is the scenario.

```
String strText = "ABC abc Abc aBC abC aBc ABc AbC";
// Adding a HTML content to this
String searchText = "abc";
String strFormatted = strText.replaceAll(
    "(?i)" + searchText, 
    "<font color='red'>" + searchText + "</font>");
```

This returns a string with all the words in lower case and of course in red color.
My requirement is to get the `strFormatted` as a String with the case same as Original String but it should have the Font tag.

Is it possible to do this ?

Comment: Here, according to your code, the original string will be in `strText` and the formatted string will be in `strFormatted`.

Comment: Yeah this is not the real code.. This one i just make up. Anyways the thing is I want the preserve the case of strText in strFormatted after replacement with the font tags..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a backreference. Something like:

```
String strFormatted = strText.replaceAll(
    "(?i)(" + searchText + ")", 
    "<font color='red'>$1</font>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest an alternative using [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

```
String [] strText = {"ABC", "abc","Abc", "aBC", "abC", "aBc", "ABc", "AbC"};

    ArrayList<String> abc = new ArrayList<String> ();
       for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
        {

           if("abc".equalsIgnoreCase(strText[j]))
                  {
                      abc.add("<font color='red'>"+strText[j]+"</font>");
                  }
        }

   String strFormatted = abc.toString();
   System.out.println(strFormatted);
```

Comment: Why would you suggest that? Performance? Maintainability? Some other reason?