# Replace all occurrences of word in string but maintain case of original word

Tags: java, html, string, replace, jsoup

I am adding search functionality to a project. When a search term is entered my program loops through an html string and replaces all occurrences of that word with the search term surrounded by a span tag. the replaceAll() method replaces the words but its not exactly what i want to do. I do not know how to maintain the case of the original word. For example if i search for 'hello': 'Hello' becomes 'hello', 'HELLO' becomes 'hello'. For parsing the html i am using jsoup.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);   
Elements elemenets = doc.body().getAllElements();

        for (int i = 1; i < elemenets.size(); i++) {
            String elementText = elemenets.get(i).text();

            if (elementText.toLowerCase().contains(search_term.toLowerCase())) {

                elemenets.get(i).html(elemenets.get(i).html().replaceAll("(?i)" + search_term, "<span id = 'first' style ='background-color:#fbaf5d;'>" + search_term + "</span>"));
            }

        }
String result = doc.toString();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753163/how-can-i-perform-case-insensitive-pattern-search-and-case-preserving-replacemen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working. I needed to use regEx and replace my search_term in the second argument of replaceAll with $1. RegEx is still a bit of a mystery to me. Thanks for the help everybody!

```
elemenets.get(i).html(elemenets.get(i).html().replaceAll("(?i)(" + search_term + ")", "<span>$1</span>"));
```

Comment: If your search term is "hello" then the regex is `"(?i)(hello)"`.  The `(?i)` tells the matcher that it should treat upper and lower case letters the same in the succeeding matches.  The letters `hello` just match those letters literally, but they will match both upper and lower case because of `(?i)`.  Portions in parentheses (that don't start with `(?`) are _capture groups_.  They tell the matcher that whatever it matches, to save it.  So when it matches `hello`, `HeLlO`, or whatever, it saves that string.  `$1` means use the contents of the first capture group.  Hope that helps.

Comment: (Since I ran out of room in my last comment) `$1` only works in replacement strings, by the way.  Replacement strings aren't regexes and don't have the same commands.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using some regex?
Take a look at this question about the same problem
[Use Java and RegEx to convert casing in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770967/use-java-and-regex-to-convert-casing-in-a-string/2770977#2770977)

I hope it will help you