# Replace an insensitive substring, keeping the case

Tags: java, android, string, replace

I need to highlight a TextView in a ListView in Android and looking [at CommonsWare response here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview) I've decided to use the .setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString) method.
So in my adapter I have this formatString() method.

I got 2 problems:

1) It doesn't seem to work.

2) Even if it would work, it would be limited, because the fullString can be all UpperCase, all LowerCase or with a Upper Case char as the first char in a word.

The textToHighlight will only be at the beginning of words in fullString.

```
private String formatString(String textToHighlight, String fullString) {
        if (textToHighlight== null || textToHighlight.equals("")) {
            return fullString;
        }
        String colore = "\"#0099CC\"";

        String htmlSubString = "<font color=" + colore + ">"
                + textToHighlight+ "!</font>";

        fullString.replace(textToHighlight, htmlString);

        return fullString;
    }
```

Output should be:

```
a) formatString("ca", "Cake Maccaroni") = "<font color=\"#0099CC\">Ca</font>ke Maccaroni"
b) formatString("ca", "CAKE MACCARONI") = "<font color=\"#0099CC\">CA</font>KE MACCARONI"
c) formatString("ca", "Maccaroni Cake") = "Maccaroni <font color=\"#0099CC\">Ca</font>ke"
d) formatString("ca", "MACCARONI CAKE") = "MACCARONI <font color=\"#0099CC\">CA</font>KE"
e) formatString("ca", "cake maccaroni") = "<font color=\"#0099CC\">ca</font>ke maccaroni"
```

Comment: Question 2 is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753163/how-can-i-perform-case-insensitive-pattern-search-and-case-preserving-replacemen

Comment: You're right, it works, could find it before. Should I provide the answer in a new Answer, edit on the question or just shut up?

Comment: I don't think we need to say anything more.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the result of the `fullString.replace(textToHighlight, htmlString);` method to a value, if you want to use it. `return fullString.replace(textToHighlight, htmlString);` should solve the first problem.

Answer (score 1):

`String` objects are immutable. That means that there is no way to change the content of a `String` object once it has been initialized.

The `replace()` method does not change the `String` object you call it on; instead, it returns a new `String` object with the replacement that you wanted to do.

You're not doing anything with the return value of the `replace()` method, so your code has no effect. You're just returning the original string. Change your code to return the result of the `replace()` method:

```
return fullString.replace(textToHighlight, htmlString);
```

To solve your other problem, you'll need to make your method more sophisticated. You could do that by using `replaceFirst()` instead of `replace()`, which takes a regular expression as the first argument (instead of a plain string). You'll have to build the regular expression carefully from `textToHighlight` and your requirements.